# Unit testing extended AEM core component - delegate pattern null reference exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, aem

I am trying to write a unit test for an extended AEM core component - a 'button' with an extra field. I use the delegation pattern, and Lombok to reduce implementation code.

My unit test is failing when attempting to get the button ID (inherited from the button super-type) - with a null reference exception - because 'button' is null.

**Why would that be? Have I set up my unit test incorrectly? Or could it be that I have used the delegation pattern for the core component incorrectly?**

It is driving me crazy!

INTERFACE:

```
@ProviderType
public interface ExtendedButton extends Button {
    String RESOURCE_TYPE = "myproject/components/extendedbutton";

    String getVariant();
}
```

IMPL:

```
@Model(
    adaptables = { Resource.class, SlingHttpServletRequest.class },
    adapters = { ExtendedButton.class, Button.class, ComponentExporter.class },
    resourceType = ExtendedButton.RESOURCE_TYPE,
    defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL
)
@Exporter(name = ExporterConstants.SLING_MODEL_EXPORTER_NAME, extensions = ExporterConstants.SLING_MODEL_EXTENSION)
public class ExtendedButtonImpl implements ExtendedButton {
    @Delegate
    @Self
    @Via(type = ResourceSuperType.class)
    private Button button;

    @ValueMapValue
    @Getter
    private String variant;

    // EXAMPLE
    // without lombok, the getter for button ID would be;
    public String getId() {
        return (null != button) ? button.getId() : null;
    }
}
```

UNIT TEST CODE:

```
@ExtendWith(AemContextExtension.class)
class ExtendedButtonModelTest {
    private final AemContext context = new AemContextBuilder()
            .plugin(CORE_COMPONENTS)
            .build();

    private ExtendedButton model;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        context.create().resource("/apps/myproject/components/extendedbutton",
                PROPERTY_RESOURCE_SUPER_TYPE, "core/wcm/components/button/v2/button");

        Page page = context.create().page("/content/test-page");

        context.currentResource(context.create().resource(page, "extendedbutton",
                PROPERTY_RESOURCE_TYPE, ExtendedButton.RESOURCE_TYPE,
                JCR_TITLE, "button text",

                "variant", "light",

                "id", "button id",
                "linkURL", "https://google.com",
                "linkTarget", "_blank",
                "accessibilityLabel", "button label"
        ));

        model = context.request().adaptTo(ExtendedButton.class);
    }

    // UNIT TEST SUCCEEDS
    @Test
    void testGetVariant() {
        String val = model.getVariant();
        assertNotNull(val);
        assertEquals("light", val);
    }

    // UNIT TEST THROWS NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ON MODEL
    @Test
    void testGetButtonId() {
        String val = model.getId();
        assertNotNull(val);
        assertEquals("button-id", val);
    }
}
```

Comment: _It is driving me crazy!_ - yeah, Lombok has a way of doing that. Especially when you use [experimental features](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate). *Currently we feel this feature will not move out of experimental status anytime soon, and support for this feature may be dropped if future versions of javac or ecj make it difficult to continue to maintain the feature.*. I really wouldn't worry too much about getting this to work. It's a bit of extra boilerplate, yes, but I'll take boring predictability over curious Abstract Syntax Tree manipulation any day.

Comment: The issue though in this case; is not with Lombok - I probably didn't make it clear in my question. Even with the extra boilerplate getter, the 'button' is still null. THAT is my issue. Writing my own getter would be a bit 'cleaner' than lombok, i.e. it would return null instead of throwing the exception, but then my unit test would fail on the null assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my! This turned out to be a very, very simple issue. In the above unit test code, I used two constants;

```
PROPERTY_RESOURCE_SUPER_TYPE
PROPERTY_RESOURCE_TYPE
```

These were incorrect - and from the wrong import library, since they were "**resourceSuperType**" and "**resourceType**" respectively - missing the "**sling:**" prefix!!!!!!

The correct constants, are;

```
import static org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.api.JcrResourceConstants.SLING_RESOURCE_SUPER_TYPE_PROPERTY;
import static org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.api.JcrResourceConstants.SLING_RESOURCE_TYPE_PROPERTY;
```

The fundamental line to the unit test, being;

```
context.create().resource("/apps/myproject/components/extendedbutton",
                SLING_RESOURCE_SUPER_TYPE_PROPERTY, "core/wcm/components/button/v2/button");
```

which instructs the unit test which core component to extend from.